# Electromagnetic force harmonics in time and space in Python

Tags: python, numpy, fft

I have to calculate radial force harmonics of an electrical motor and represent them in time and space. The method used to find radial forces is Maxwell Stress Tensor (the method is implemented in a FEM solver: Gmsh and from there I obtained the values for radial and tangential flux density). I imported in Python all datas and here I wrote the expression for radial force, something like this:

```
def integrateForces (Axiallength,dtheta,Rad,br,bt):    
    integral_rad =0
    for i in range(len(br)):
        integral_rad +=  (1/(2*mu0)*(br[i]*br[i]-bt[i]*bt[i])*Axiallength*Rad*dtheta)
    return integral_rad
```

And now I want to represent fft of radial force in time and space, but I don't know how. All I got is fft in time, and the code is this:

```
Fs = 100   #sampling frequency
n  = 145   #number of samples
t = np.linspace(0,n/Fs,n)   # time vector
y =  fradial
def plotFFT(t,y,Fs,n):
    fft_v = np.fft.fft(y)
    fft_pow = np.abs(fft_v)/t.shape[-1]
    freq = np.fft.fftfreq(t.shape[-1],d=t[2]-t[1])
    # basically fftfreq returns the frequencies
    pl.figure(figsize=(8,5))
    pl.xlabel('Frequency [Hz]',fontsize =13)
    pl.ylabel('Power spectrum',fontsize =13)
    baseline = pl.stem(freq,fft_pow)
    pl.axis([-0.1,100,0,45])
    pl.xscale('symlog', linthreshx=0.1)
    pl.yscale('symlog', linthreshx=0.1)
    pl.setp(baseline, 'color','b', 'linewidth', 2)
    pl.grid()
    pl.show()

plotFFT(t,y,Fs,n)
```

Any idea will be helpful. Thank you !